# Nested OR conditions in azure synapse

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a filter activity that filters out files base on specific values.
currently I am using @contains(item().name,'KU001') to check if 'KU001' is present in the file Name. But I want to check multiple conditions in OR so that if any of the matching values are found it filters out.

So in addition to it I also need to check 'KU002' , 'KU001','KU004' are present in file names.
Since '@contains' cannot be nested, and we cannot add multiple 'OR' conditions what could be the best possible approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your `KU___` items are more**, then you can try the below approach.

First create an array of your `KU___` items like below.

```
@createArray('KU001','KU002','KU003','KU004')
```

Create these variable in the pipeline.

[image]

Give this array to a ForEach activity and check the **Sequential** box in it.

Inside ForEach, use the set variable activities and filter activities combination like below.

When using filter activity inside a for loop, `@item()` value will be taken from filter activity. So, to compare the `item` from for each activity, first store the current `@item()` of for-loop in a variable.

[image]

Then use filter activity. Give your `names array`(values to filter) to this and in condition, use this expression.

```
@contains(item().name,variables('cur_item'))
```

[image]

This will filter out the matching records in every iteration, but to avoid the duplication of matching records, use **union** of the `res`(empty array in first iteration) and `filter output array` and store it in a `temp_arr` array with below expression.

```
@union(variables('res'),activity('Filter1').output.Value)
```

[image]

To do this in every iteration, reassign the `temp_arr` array to `res` array.

[image]

After ForEach, the required filtered values will be stored in the `res` variable like below.

[image]

**If your  `KU___` items are less**, then you can directly use `@or()` function in the filter activity instead of the for-loop approach like below.

```
@or(or(contains(item().name,'KU001'),contains(item().name,'KU002')),or(contains(item().name,'KU003'),contains(item().name,'KU004')))
```

You can use any of the above approach as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciated... was stuck in this for few days...life saver